# CSS styling targeting elements in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

My Forms app is reading in a feed and the content provider wants to use HTML

The preferred way of doing it would be to leverage CSS, but I haven't been able to determine how to target an element

For example, no problem setting text colour like so:

```
.newsPageBody {
color: pink;
}
```

Works fine. This however, does not:

```
.newsPageBody h1 {
    color: green;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this, short of marking up the whole incoming feed?

Answer (score 0):

There're several methods to select element using css.

You could look at [Selecting elements and applying properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/#selecting-elements-and-applying-properties). and [Styling Xamarin.Forms Apps with CSS](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2018/04/01/styling-xamarin-forms.aspx)

1. Selecting elements by type

   ```
   stacklayout {

      margin: 20;
    }
   ```
2. Selecting elements by base class

   ```
   ^Entry {
     font-size: 30;
     background-color: white;
     margin: 10 0;
     color: #0A100D;
    }
   ```
3. Selecting an element by name

   ```
   #listView {
     background-color: lightgray;
   }

   <ListView x:Name="listView" ...>
       ...
   </ListView>
   ```
4. Selecting elements with a specific class attribute

   ```
   .detailPageTitle {
      font-style: bold;
      font-size: medium;
      text-align: center;
    }

   .detailPageSubtitle {
      text-align: center;
      font-style: italic;
    }

   <Label ... StyleClass="detailPageTitle" />
   <Label ... StyleClass="detailPageSubtitle"/>
   ```

and so on.

Comment: Forgive me being stupid but I don't see that any of these examples shows how to solve the problem I highlighted above, which was about targeting a specific HTML tag, like H1?